# Semantics of `errno`

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, language-lawyer, errno, reserved-words

I tried searching the standards but couldn't find anything specific regarding `errno`.

What I mean is some implementations define `errno` as a global variable while some define it as a macro

```
#define errno (*_err_no())
```

The standard doesn't include it in the list of reserved keywords for identifiers.

This means that I should be able to use errno as a local variable. While it should be fine for the first implementation (that defines it as a global), the second one wouldn't be fine.

Is use of `errno` implementation defined or am I missing something?

Comment: I think this applies: [7.5p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5p2) "If a macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual object, **or a program defines an identifier with the name errno**, the behavior is undefined." Under [7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) it also says "All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) **and errno** are always reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the latest C11 draft (N1570), [**7.5 Errors `<errno.h>`**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5) (emphasis mine):

> The header `<errno.h>` defines several **macros**, all relating to the reporting of error conditions.
>
> The macros are
>
> ```
> EDOM
> EILSEQ
> ERANGE
> ```
>
> which expand to integer constant expressions with type `int`, distinct positive values, and which are suitable for use in `#if` preprocessing directives; and
>
> ```
> errno
> ```
>
> which expands to a modifiable lvalue that has type `int` and thread local storage duration, the value of which is set to a positive error number by several library functions.
>   If a macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual object, **or a program defines an identifier with the name `errno`, the behavior is undefined**.

This pretty clearly defines `errno` as a macro, and reserves its name in all scopes.

Comment: I must have missed this section. I was trying to look for it being mentioned as a reserved keyword for identifier naming. The last line you cited clears it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From the standard :

> The  header `<errno.h>` defines  several  macros,  all  relating  to  the  reporting  of  error conditions.
>
> The macros are
>
> ```
> EDOM
> EILSEQ
> ERANGE
> ```
>
> which expand to integer constant expressions with type `int`, distinct positive values, and which are suitable for use in `#if` preprocessing directives; and
>
> ```
> errno
> ```
>
> which  **expands  to  a  modifiable  lvalue that  has  type `int`** and  thread  local  storage duration, the value of which is set to a positive error number by several library functions.

(emphasis is mine)

So if the implementation defines error as `*_err_no()`, then `_err_no()` should return the location of that int, and `*_err_no()` accesses that location to be edited.

Answer (score 1):

It is well defined by the [C-Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **7.5 Errors**
>
> 1. The header  defines several macros, all relating to the reporting of error
>      conditions.
> 2. 2 The macros are
>      EDOM
>      EILSEQ
>      ERANGE
>      which expand to integer constant expressions with type int, distinct positive values, and
>      which are suitable for use in #if preprocessing directives; and
>      errno
>      which expands to a modifiable lvalue201) that has type int and thread local storage
>      duration, the value of which is set to a positive error number by several library functions.
>      **If a macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual object, or a program
>      defines an identifier with the name errno, the behavior is undefined**.
> 3. The value of errno in the initial thread is zero at program startup
>      (the initial value of errno in other threads is an indeterminate
>      value), but is never set to zero by any library function.202) The
>      value of errno may be set to nonzero by a library function call
>      whether or not there is an error, provided the use of errno is not
>      documented in the description of the function in this International
>      Standard.
> 4. Additional macro definitions, beginning with E and a digit or E and
>      an uppercase letter,203) may also be specified by the
>      implementation.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>